# Erro em AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(s));

Tags: java, eclipse

> Eu crio uma classe para criar o AudioPlayer

```
package Audio;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class AudioPlayer {

private Clip clip;

public AudioPlayer(String s) {

    try {

        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(s));
        AudioFormat baseFormat = ais.getFormat();
        AudioFormat decodeFormat = new AudioFormat(
            AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
            baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
            16,
            baseFormat.getChannels(),
            baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
            baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
            false
        );
        AudioInputStream dais =
            AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                decodeFormat, ais);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(dais);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void play() {
    if(clip == null) return;
    stop();
    clip.setFramePosition(0);
    clip.start();
}

public void stop() {
    if(clip.isRunning()) clip.stop();
}

public void close() {
    stop();
    clip.close();
}
}
```

> então eu tento colocar no menu do meu jogo (GameState):

```
[...]
import Audio.AudioPlayer;
[...]
    private AudioPlayer bgMusic;
[...]
        bgMusic = new AudioPlayer("Resources/Musics/menu.mp3");
        bgMusic.play();
```

> E então recebo esse erro:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javazoom.spi.mpeg.sampled.file.MpegAudioFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
at Audio.AudioPlayer.<init>(AudioPlayer.java:13)
at GameState.MenuState.<init>(MenuState.java:38)
at GameState.GameStateManager.loadState(GameStateManager.java:30)
at GameState.GameStateManager.<init>(GameStateManager.java:24)
at main.GamePanel.init(GamePanel.java:64)
at main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:70)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

> Alguém pode me ajudar???

**EDIT:**

Eu tinha o JDK 7, instalei o 8, por causa do JavaFX, mas estou com um problema no 8... isso já é outra história...

Mas, eu peguei essa Classe(AudioPlayer) desse vídeo:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ar0hTsb9sxM

E ele usou uma música em MP3, então estou meio duvidoso....

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue carregar o stream sem problema aqui: ?

```
bgMusic = new AudioPlayer("Resources/Musics/menu.mp3");
```

O caminho para o arquivo me parece errado. No fim das contas ele vai lançar um null pointer exception por não conseguir carregar os streams.
Primeiramente tente utilizar um caminho completo, ex:

```
c:/arquivo.mp3
```

Logo depois verifique o caminho relativo ao arquivo `.mp3`

**Edit:**

Realmente não é possível reproduzir oque você procura, até onde pesquisei, AudioPlayer só reprododuz `.wav` ou `.mid`, porém achei uma ótima alternativa no seu caso [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java):

```
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
...
String bip = "bip.mp3";
Media hit = new Media(bip);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

Note que são dos pacotes do javafx.

Comment: Oi, tentei asssim: Copiei o MP3 Para o Disco Local, e tentei abrir assim: 'bgMusic = new AudioPlayer("C:/menu.mp3");' mas deu o mesmo erro, e, eu estou usando o Eclipse. Vlw

Comment: Atualizado, de uma olhada.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta :)

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser executar um arquivo MP3 em JAVA você consegue importando a classe [BigClip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667454/playing-mp3-using-java-sound-api/5668510#5668510) para o seu projeto e adicionando o [mp3plugin.jar](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0) ao seu build path.

Feito isso é só implementar o seguinte pedaço de código ao seu programa:

```
BigClip musica = new BigClip();

musica.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("arquivo.mp3")));

musica.start();
```

Não se esquecendo de adicionar um JFrame ou um loop infinito para não parar a execução do seu programa.